# Optimize the Entity Framework Find method

Tags: entity-framework

Here is how I get an operation by Id!

```
 Operation operation = db.Operations.Find(id):;
```

I would like to optimize this line of code! As I don't want to send the request when id has no value. So I wrote the following line.

```
    Operation operation = id.HasValue? db.Operations.Find(id):null;
```

But I wonder if I'm reinventing the wheel! Does the E.F `Find` method query the database when the parameter is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy to test using SQL Server profiler. Against a generic IdentityContext:

```
int? id = 0;
var user = db.Users.Find(id);
```

Sql profiler result:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (2) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=0
```

Same again with a null value

```
int? id = null
var user = db.Users.Find(id);
```

SQL profiler doesn't log a query.

So it looks like your `.HasValue` check is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank You @J Tolley that was very kind!